# DB call terminates the program

Tags: ruby

I have a program written in Ruby with Sql Server 2008 on the back end. Right now I am confronting a problem which I am going to discuss under the following.

Consider I have `functionA()` and `functionB()`. `fuctionA()` and `functionB()` are being called in a loop. Of course it DB, connections are open and closed after each call inside these function.

I have a Rufus Scheduler scheduled after 1m which calls `fuctionA()` in its own thread by default. When `functionA()` in Rufus triggers the program terminates keeping in mind that `functionA()` and `functionB()` are being run constantly in a loop. When I comment out `functionA()` in Rufus the program executes smoothly. What could be the reason? Please guide.

```
class TestRufus
```

def initialize
 @dps = nil
 @mu = Mutex.new
 end
  def get_data()
    victim_device  = VictimDevice.new()
    app_config = YAML.load_file("#{File.dirname(**FILE**)}/../../config/sa.gw.c.victim.yml") 
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new
    scheduler.every "10s" do
      handle_rufus
    end

```
loop do              
   begin           
   @mu.synchronize  {
   @dps = victim_device.get_device_proximitysett(8)
    }     
    puts "DeviceID : #{@dps.device_id} AlertDistance: #{@dps.victim_prox_alert_dist} VoilationDistance : #{@dps.victim_prox_viol_dist}"       
    rescue => e
    time_of_error = Time.now.gmtime.to_s()           
    puts("Error occurred: #{time_of_error} - #{e.message}")

    end       
end
end #end of function

def  handle_rufus()
puts 'In Rufus.' 
begin
    @mu.synchronize  {
  @dps = victim_device.get_device_proximitysett(8)
  }
  rescue => e
    puts 'Error #{e.message}'
  end  
  puts "Rufus got! #{@dps.device_id} "
  puts 'Out Rufus.'              
end
```

end # end of class

obj= TestRufus.new
  obj.get_data()

Thank you in advance.

Comment: If the problem gone when you comment out `functionA()`, it's mean that the problem in this function. To further investigation we need to see code of you functions to be able reproduce the problem at our side.

Comment: you can view the test code now